# 'Type mismatch for Index Key' on using a sort key in DynamoDB

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with the following indices:

- User

  - id (string, primary)
  - email (string, global secondary)
  - expiresOn (Date (string), global secondary)
  - is_premium (boolean)

I'd like to have `is_premium` be the range / sort key of `expiresOn`, so I could e.g query all accounts which are expiring before or on today's date, AND which have is_premium = true.

If i just queried for all accounts expiring before / on today, but without is_premium=true, I would get 90% of the table in the results.

But, if I try to set a range query on `is_premium`, I get the following error when I try to save a record to the table:

> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Type mismatch for Index Key
>   (Service: null; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException;
>   Request ID: null)
>
> at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.embedded.DDBExceptionMappingInvocationHandler.handleDynamoDBLocalServiceException(DDBExceptionMappingInvocationHandler.java:76)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.embedded.DDBExceptionMappingInvocationHandler.invoke(DDBExceptionMappingInvocationHandler.java:58)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.putItem(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doPutItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1270)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$1.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:879)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:1120)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:966)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:758)

I get this on `dynamoDbMapper.save(order)`

If I remove the sort / range key, everything works.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? The error is very ambigious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boolean field is not supported for hash/range keys in dynamodb. (only string/number/binary are supported).

you need to convert it to STRING or NUMBER (or to add new column). (if this will be your range key, so it can be 'true'/'false' or 0/1). if it was your hash key so it can be more complicated.

Comment: Is there a workaround e.g using a local secondary index on premium?

Comment: What about using 0 or 1 instead of a boolean?

Comment: @birnbaum Its just that using a boolean works nicely with java's type safety features.

Comment: @EyalCh So if I set the column type to string or number when creating the table, but in my java classes I map the column as a boolean, will the java mapper figure it out and continue to work?

Comment: I am not using java, so i dont know how your library use it, but this map should be done at application level..

Answer (score 1):

Booleans are no valid hash/range key in DynamoDB. A possible solution to make the architecture you suggested work would be to modify your data mapper to map booleans on 0 and 1.

But this way you could only query for a specific expiration date and then check if the according user is premium or not. If I understood your use case correctly, what you want is all `is_premium =true` within a certain `expiresOn` timeframe. In this case the preferable architecture would be:

- `is_premium` as the global secondary partition key
- `expiresOn` as the global secondary sort key

This way you can query the `is_premium` partition and use the sort key to e.g. filter out all items in this partition that expire within one day.

Comment: Is there a performance advantage to putting the GSI on `is_premium` vs `expiresOn`?

Comment: To be clear: The GSI consists out of a partition and a sort key. When you do a query in DynamoDB, you always _have_ to provide the exact partition key value. That means if `expiresOn` would be your partition key, a query on this GSI would need to contain a very specific `expiresOn` value and could not contain a range or something. This is why `expiresOn` should be your sort key.

Comment: I see. That explains a lot. Hmm, I've ended up making a new table containing only the records where `premium = true`, and I'm doing a scan with a filter which does `expiresOn <= :val`. How does that compare to this? Is it more efficient to do it this way?

Comment: The architecture I supposed is preferable because filters are applied _after_ scans/queries and have no influence on the `ScannedCount`. That means a scan with filter has to look at all entries in the table, while a query with `is_premium` as partition key and `expiresOn` as sort key is only looking at the entries that you really want. Also maintaining two tables just for easier queries is not very good practice because of unnecessary complexity.

Comment: The only reason why I'm avoiding setting an index on `premium` is, I'd like to map it as a boolean in my java class. If in the db its mapped as an integer or string, could I still map it as a boolean in java?